# how to downgrade the vmware file

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine, vmware

I am running the vmware version suitable for macOS high sierra.

But the file created to run the linux is in the higher version of the vmware software and this is not getting compatible.

How should I execute the VMware file?

I am having vmware file to install linux VM but I cannot install it as the VMware version which I can run on MacOS High Sierra is not compatible with the file of Linux VM as it is created on Higher version

Basically the issue is of the version compatibility between the Linux VM file and VMware version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Hicomputer please check the update in the question above

Comment: Is installing the VM from scratch, using an ISO an option? This is the same way that you would go about installing the OS on a physical computer using a CD drive.

Comment: The hardware compatibility of an already created VM can't be downgraded except for some really old versions. With VMWare Fusion 11.5 the VM has to be Virtual Hardware Version 16 or less.  Newer versions of VMWare Fusion can create VMs with a lower Virtual Hardware Version so they can be used more widely but will miss out on some features introduced with latter versions.

Comment: VMware Workstation Pro should be able to downgrade virtual hardware versions.  Since it doesn't require powering on VMs, you can do it with a trial version without a license.  However, you'd also need a Windows or Linux machine (possibly a VM) to run VMware Workstation Pro.